# How to integrate HLS.js with angular?

Tags: video-streaming, angular8, hls.js

I am building a video streaming website using angular.

I will be using HLS protocol to stream videos to the website with adaptive multi-bitrate streaming (The video bitrate should automatically change based on the user's network speed).

I have found hls npm player which supports adaptive bitrate streaming with HLS (https://www.npmjs.com/package/hls.js/v/canary).

I have also set up the workflows to create an HLS stream for my videos and have successfully streamed them through the hls npm player demo available on (https://hls-js.netlify.com/demo).

I need to know how to integrate the above player with angular 8.

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem?